# Graph Theory (degree of the vertices of a graph when it can be partitioned into two trees)

Tags: graph, tree

Show that if the edge set of a graph G(V,E) with n nodes

can be partitioned into 2 trees,

then there is at least one vertex of degree less than 4 in G.

...................................................................................

I have tried to prove this problem with the help of the method of contradiction.

Assume that all vertices of the graph G has degree >= 4.

Assume the graph G is partitioned into two trees T1 and T2.

With the help of the above assumptions the only observation I could make is that for every vertex v in G

degree of v must be greater than or equal to 2 in either T1 or T2.

I don't know how proceed with this. Please help.

If my approach for solving this problem is wrong then please provide a different solution.

Comment: Maybe I miss something but leaf-vertex degree in tree is 1, no?

Comment: Yes the degree of a leaf in a graph is one but the question is asking about the degree of the vertices of the graph G.

Comment: So if you proved that every v has degree of 2 or more in both T1 and T2 then in T1 and T2 there are no leafs -> has circle -> no tree

Comment: No, I have not proved that what I got is that every v has degree 2 or more in either T1 or T2 not both.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2823289/14578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started with a good approach. Lets assume all vertices in G has degree of 4 (or above) and sssume the graph G is partitioned into two trees T1 and T2.

We know that number of edge in tree is n-1 (when n is number of vertices). Therefor in each of T1 and T2 we have n-1 edges (consider n to be |V|) -> combine we have 2n-2 edges in G -> |E| = 2n-2

From the other hand we know that each v in G -> d(v) > 4 . And we know that sum of degree in graph equal to 2|E|. therefor, 2*|E| >= 4*n (I took the minimum degree for each vertex and each edge contribute 2 to the sum of the degree). So we got |E| >= 2*n.

Contradiction -> There is have to be one vertex with degree less then 4